# What is the right way to create MySQL procedure that count numbers?

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

I tried to make it like that, but it returns only single row.
The procedure exit after the first select.

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS testProc;
DELIMITER $$
    CREATE PROCEDURE testProc(start_stamp INT, end_stamp INT, step INT)
    BEGIN
        DECLARE tmpStep INT;
        SET tmpStep = start_stamp;
        WHILE tmpStep < end_stamp DO
            SELECT tmpStep;
            SET tmpStep = tmpStep + step;
        END WHILE;
    END$$
DELIMITER ;

CALL testProc (1,10,1);
```

The desired behavior is to return the numbers from 1 to 10 in this case.

Comment: Works fine in my end, but you're returning them as separate result sets. How do you execute this code? From a connector or using the command-line utility?

Comment: @MatsKindahl You are right, the connector returned just the first select. How I can return all the results as a single result set?

Comment: It varies between the connectors. For the C API you use `mysql_more_results` and `mysql_next_result` to iterate over the result sets (http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/c-api-multiple-queries.html).

Comment: @MatsKindahl Is there a way to aggregate the result sets in the procedure itself and at the end to return the aggregated result as single result set. This way there will be no any dependencies from the connectors used.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To create a procedure that return a dynamically generated result set, you have to create a temporary table internally and then select it. The following code should do the job for you:

```
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS testProc;
DELIMITER $$
CREATE PROCEDURE testProc(start_stamp INT, end_stamp INT, step INT)
BEGIN
    DECLARE tmpStep INT;
    DROP TABLE IF EXISTS `testProc$tmp`;
    CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE `testProc$tmp` (a INT);
    SET tmpStep = start_stamp;
    WHILE tmpStep < end_stamp DO
        INSERT INTO `testProc$tmp` VALUES(tmpStep);
        SET tmpStep = tmpStep + step;
    END WHILE;
    SELECT * FROM `testProc$tmp`;
END$$
DELIMITER ;

CALL testProc (1,10,1);
```

Note that this code will leave the temporary table hanging around after the function call, but the name is created to be "obscure" so that it do not clash with some other table.

Comment: Thank you for the advice, but this procedure has to be called simultaneously in multiuser environment, and produce meaningful results for each user, so sharing one and the same temporary table is not an option I am afraid.

Comment: Each temporary table is specific for the connection, so if you are using different connections, there is no issue. In other words, temporary table 'foo' on one connection is different from temporary table 'foo' on another connection.